# Error with Pig on Local machine

Tags: hadoop, installation, apache-pig

I am a newbie so pardon me if the question appears to be very silly. I have installed hadoop 1.2.1 and the basic wordcount example works fine on my local so as the next level of exploration i installed Pig 0.13.0.

When i just tried running pig -help it seemed to work fine. But when i run pig version i get an IOException as below:

```
14/08/06 01:00:08 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
14/08/06 01:00:08 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
14/08/06 01:00:08 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2014-08-06 01:00:08,321 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.13.0 (r1606446) compiled Jun 29 2014, 02:29:34
2014-08-06 01:00:08,322 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/<user>/pig/log/pig_1407301208318.log
2014-08-06 01:00:09,856 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File version does not exist.
Details at logfile: /home/<user>/pig/log/pig_1407301208318.log
```

The content of the log file is as below:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File version does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:255)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFilesInternal(FileLocalizer.java:778)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFile(FileLocalizer.java:722)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:550)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

It would be great if someone could help me understand what needs to be done to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think nothing is wrong, pig will run fine. The problem is that you used this command:

```
pig version
```

But you should use

```
pig -version
```

Think you will get same error when write `pig help`.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
pig -version
```

if you give pig version alone, then it searching for the file named 'version'.